# How to generate series of ascending number that include date element?

Tags: java, numbers, generator

Hello. I want to create a function that generates ascending numbers.
For example, if today's date is June 21st, 2013 then the numbers will be 130621001.
The last three digits are ascending numbers, and it'll reset back to 001 on each date.
I can figure out on how to make the date digits, but I'm stuck with those last three digits.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can store the last tree digits in memory or files, when create new number, increase the last three digits and restore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, good luck

```
public static String NextNumber(String currentNumber) {
    //assume yymmddnnn
    String sDateNum = currentNumber.substring(0, 6);
    String sCurrentNum = currentNumber.substring(6,9);
    int i = Integer.valueOf("1" + sCurrentNum);
    i++;

    return sDateNum + String.valueOf(i).substring(1, 4);
}



    System.out.println(NextNumber("130621001"));
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it myself.  if vebry already handle the date digit + "001" step, this function will return the next number.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is how you know what your previous answer was.

```
today = myDateFormatter(System.currentTimeMillis());
if (today.equals(oldDay)) count++;
else count == 0;
oldDay = today;
```

If this is a long running process, oldDay and count can be simple fields in your class.  If the process exits and restarts, you will need to get your old answers from somewhere and set them to the largest value.

Comment: Ok, now it get it. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @verby Glad it helped.  Please remember to upvote the answers that helped and checkmark the most helpful one.  And welcome to StackOverflow.